# Removing names of pruned directories from output of find command

Tags: shell, find

I'm trying to use the find command to generate a list of source files within a directory and only some of its subdirectories. Example:

```
/Source_Files
    /dontexclude
        dontexclude.h
        dontexclude.c
    /exclude
        exclude.c
        exclude.h
    main.c
    test.c
    test.h
```

I want a list of files ending in '.c' and '.h', and I want to exclude the contents of the /exclude subdirectory.

`find -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -o -path '*/exclude' -prune` produces this output:

```
./test.h
./exclude
./test.c
./main.c
./dontexclude/dontexclude.c
./dontexclude/dontexclude.h
```

How can I use `find` to produce the above list without "./exclude"?

Comment: This is due to implicit print of find results. Add an explicit `-print` (or `-printf`) to the files that must be printed and pruned directories won't be printed anymore. See Stéphane Chazelas' answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -name excludeme -prune -o \
  \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -print
```

Remember that *AND* (implicit) has precedence over *OR* (`-o`). (see also `-name '*.[ch]'`)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest change is to replace `-prune` (don't look no more in this directory), with `-prune -false` (don't look no more in this directory, and this is not a match).

Answer (score 0):

At the cost of some extra filesystem operations limit the search to plain files. This will exclude the `exclude` directory because that's not a file:

```
find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -o -path '*/exclude' -prune \) -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

This command returns what you ask:

`find . \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -a \! \( -path './exclude/*' \)`

Comment: But still descends into `./exclude` only to exclude all the files (except those that contain invalid characters) in it.